Incrorrect network metrics values
Faced with such a problem. Grafana+Prometheus and InfluxDB+Telegraf monitoring systems are configured in my project for server network traffic visualization.
Metrics node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device="ens5"} (Prometheus) and bytes_sent (Telegraf) respectively. However, it seems to me that they are broadcasting incorrect data. Here is a cut for a certain time according to them.
Prometheus
node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device="ens5"} 6.3817878091e+10
node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device="ens5"} 6.3820102473e+10
node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device="ens5"} 6.3820320276e+10
node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device="ens5"} 6.3820437813e+10

Telegraf + InfluxDB flux query
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "net")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "bytes_sent")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r.interface == ens5)

63,813,593,960.50
63,818,323,263.75
63,820,210,649.33
63,825,585,461.67

Also slice for the same time on bmon directly on the server.
ens5                         │   2.35KiB      0      │   1.79KiB      7
ens5                         │   5.55KiB      0      │   2.46KiB     12
ens5                         │   7.74KiB      0      │   5.92KiB     35
ens5                         │  11.94KiB      0      │   3.98KiB     26
ens5                         │  38.07KiB      0      │  12.34KiB     84
ens5                         │  41.95KiB      0      │   9.78KiB     80

That is, the graph line for both metrics is quite uniform, without significant traffic jumps. However, if you look at the server, the situation is a little different.
Maybe I missed something?
